# WPF DataTemplate: Location of inflated storyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, datatemplate

I have a `DataTemplate` for an `ItemsControl` which is working fine. There is a `DataTrigger` in the `DataTemplate` which contains a `BeginStoryboard` `EnterAction`. I am trying to wire up the `Completed` event of the storyboard to something in code behind, specifically a method on the data object, but I can be flexible about that - at the moment I just want it to run any piece of C# code when the animation has completed.

Specifying a value for the `Completed` XAML attribute does not compile as the attribute is defined inside a template so there is no specific method to wire up to. So I will need to use code behind to wire up the event manually.

To this end I have looked at the application with Snoop to try to find where in the logical or visual tree the inflated template `Storyboard`s end up. So far all I can see is a `ContentControl` created for each item, with its `ContentTemplate` set. The `Content` property of each `ContentControl` is set to its corresponding data object. The `ContentTemplate` property contains the `Triggers` collection which contain the `EnterActions` and ultimately the `Storyboard`. My question is, do all the items share a single template instance for their `ContentTemplate` property, or do they each get their own copy? If they share one, then where are the inflated triggers and storyboards created?

I've extracted the pertinent parts of my XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type m:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type m:MyControl}">
                <Grid Name="ControlRoot" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="...">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:MyDataType}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Ellipse Name="IconHighlight1" Fill="{DynamicResource GoldRadialFade}" Width="70" Height="70" StrokeThickness="0" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlighted}" Value="True">
                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose">
                                                <Storyboard Name="ConnectToMe" Duration="0:0:2.5" FillBehavior="Stop">
                                                    <DoubleAnimation To="400" Duration="0:0:1.5" Storyboard.TargetName="IconHighlight1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, I'd normally prefer to have a bool in the `DataContext` of the Item that your `Storyboard` is applying to and say call it `AnimationCompleted`

Now by modifying your `Storyboard` to

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ConnectToMe" Duration="0:0:2.5" FillBehavior="Stop">
  <DoubleAnimation To="400" Duration="0:0:1.5" Storyboard.TargetName="IconHighlight1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" FillBehavior="Stop" />
  <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext.AnimationCompleted" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
  </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="DataContext.AnimationCompleted" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:2.5" />
  </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

We toggle the bool `AnimationCompleted` to true at the end point of the animation. Hence in the property setter of `AnimationCompleted` check if the incoming `value` is `True` and trigger your corresponding function/method from there

Comment: This seems like a sensible solution, without any complex wire-up logic either. I would still be interested in how the `DataTemplate`s work under the hood to see if there is a more 'pure' way to do it, but this is probably more succinct anyway, especially being in XAML.

Comment: Well in this case each Item is "based on" the ItemTemplate which holds the Storyboard which would lead me to believe just like their Visual tree which is created per item based on the template, the Storyboard will be so as well. If they reference a Storyboard in a parent's DataContext or parent scope resource then they might be "sharing" the Storyboards.

Comment: As far as keeping them xaml only, this clearly delegates the Logic to the VM in MVVM for the Completed Action. Thereby just having the View perform View-related stuff and letting the VM handle app logic like what it's meant to do. mixing them any further is something I'd not be so tempted to do.

Comment: Do you ever have any problems with the AnimationCompleted property not being set? I've implemented the same pattern and it only seems to work intermittently.

Comment: @StephenHewlett err nope. Haven't had any issues with it. You could add `FillBehavior="HoldEnd"` to both the bool animations to force it to not toggle values out once the animation completes and see if that sorts the issue out. Add breakpoints to the `AnimationCompleted` property and check to make sure it only fires when expected and not more times than expected.

Comment: It works now. Initially I took out the first BooleanAnimation because I didn't need the start notification. Putting it back in and adding HoldEnd did the trick. Strangely it does not work without the first BooleanAnimation even though in my implementation the false value is ignored. I will look into this one day but for now my problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenHewlett The purpose of setting it to false at the start is not just to indicate a start of animation but to also reset the current state of `AnimationCompleted` from true. In your property setter if you have code along the lines of `if (_animationCompleted == value) return;`, then without resetting the bool your setter would never go any further and thus not invoke the c# function.

Comment: The code in my 'setter' (it's actually a DP with a `PropertyChangedCallback`) reset the bool immediately after it was set to true. Perhaps the animated value had precedence.